# How to disable the recognition of touch gestures in IONIC3 app specific view?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to disable **all** touch gestures over some of the views of my app. 
The user can **only** interact with the app by an external keyboard when the app is running this views. 
Ionic Docs is not very clear about this, I only found [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/%24ionicGesture/) and [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/utility/ionic.EventController/#offGesture), but I don't know where and how should I use it. I couldn't find an example.

Has someone tried something similar?

This is my development enviroment:

> cli packages:
>
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 2.0.0-rc.4    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.0.0-rc.4
>
> global packages:
>
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
>
> local packages:
>
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
>   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
>
> System:
>
> Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1    NodeJS            : v9.3.0    npm
>   : 5.5.1    OS                : Linux 4.13

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure but what about putting a transparent layer (div with height: 100% width: 100%) over those fields so you cannot touch any but it should be accessible by keyboard?

Comment: I tried putting a div with the following class:
my-invisible-overlay {
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 1000;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
 }
It didn't work. I have a hidden input with autofocus. When I touch anywhere in the screen the input loses focus.

Comment: than give the div a function which pulls back focus on a field of your choice.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your suggestion. Could you expand?

Comment: give the div a (tap)="putFocusBack()" function and focus one of the input fields within this function

Comment: I thought about that approach, but what happens with other touch events (press, pan, swipe, rotate, pinch)? Should I bind each one with a function or there is a way to do this at once?